# How to create Delta / Changed files from directories?

Tags: linux, rsync, diff

I'm trying to create a "changed files" package from one directory to another and need to find a Linux/Unix tool/utility that will be able to handle this.

Example:

- Package_1.1/ (old)
- Package_1.2/ (new)
- changed_files/ (only changed and new files and directories)

`changed_files` would be a directory containing a recursive structure of only files that have been added or changed in `Package_1.2` compared to `Package_1.1`)

**Update:** I tried using:

```
cd Package_1.2
rsync -a -c --compare-dest=../Package_1.1 . ../changed_files/
find -depth ../changed_files -type d -empty -delete
```

However there were some files that had a slightly different modified time that were copied over, yet the contents were identical. (md5 produced an identical checksum on each file). So while I think I'm close using this command, I'm still missing something.

Comment: To be clear, you want to copy files from `Package_1.2` that are different from those in `Package_1.1` into a new directory maintaining the same directory structure?

Comment: @Thor, that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

When using `rsync`, It seems that the `-c` (`--checksum`) option does not override the `-t` (`--times`) option within `-a` (`--archive`), which uses `-rlptgoD`, and thus it will still look at file modification times.

One possible solution is to use: `-rlpgoDc` rather than `-a`.
The command would look like this:

```
cd Package_1.2
rsync -rlpgoDc --compare-dest=../Package_1.1 . ../changed_files/
find -depth ../changed_files -type d -empty -delete
```

This may not be the most elegant solution, perhaps someone has a better idea of how `rsync` can do the whole job by itself.